# Use storyboard for Landscape mode and code for Portrait mode in iPad

Tags: ipad, orientation

In my app i have to use both orientation using storyboard for iPad. I am facing the problem that the frames of the text fields, are set same in code as in storyboard for landscape but when the app is run it shows the disturbed frame. But if i remove the landscape frames from code, it works fine. So, i want to set the frames for landscape in storyboard and portrait through code. How can i achieve this functionality. Please guide.